# Install issue permission and htaccess

Tags: magento2, server-setup, permissions, htaccess

I'm trying to install Magento 2. I run this for permission file and folder

```
chown -R admin:www-data /var/www/magento2
find /var/www/magento2 -type f -print0 | xargs -r0 chmod 640
find /var/www/magento2 -type d -print0 | xargs -r0 chmod 750
chmod -R g+w /var/www/magento2/{pub,var}
```

I use default Magento2 .htaccess file (permission is 660, i tried other permission like 750) but still got this error

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server. Server unable to
>   read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

I tried to add this on .htaccess file but not work

```
<Directory /mymagento2-folder/>
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

What should I check or try to see magento2 install page?

Answer (score 0):

If using Apache 2.4, try similar virtual hosts config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/magento2ce"
    ServerName magento2.vagrant
    <Directory /var/www/magento2ce>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If Apache 2.2, then replace `Require all granted` with `Allow from all`. See more details in the [official dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache.html#403-apache).

Comment: this is maybe a bad idea to grant access.

Comment: @MagenX what is better option? This one seems to be officially recommended.

Answer (score 0):

probably as you have set permissions 640, either admin or www-data is not in the game. you have to make sure that your apache web server is actually has some admin or www-data in its uid/gid

just to debug this issue set permissions 644/755

and is .htaccess available?

Answer (score 0):

Please set default permission for Magento 2 root directory by running following command:

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```

I hope it works for you.