# Trying to install magento 2 and get page_cache is not writable

Tags: magento2, permissions, error-log, file-permissions

I'm trying to deploy magento 2.1.3 installed with composer on a CentOS 7 machine with apache 2.4 and it returns the error:

```
[Mon Jul 03 17:15:55.678068 2017] [:error] [pid 16315] [client 211.159.221.63:61183] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir "/var/www/html/var/page_cache" is not writable in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(180): Zend_Cache::throwException('cache_dir "/var...')\n#1 /var/www/html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(87): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('/var/www/html/v...')\n#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(153): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array)\n#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true)\n#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(155): Zend_Cache::factory('Magento\\\\Framewo...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, Array, true, true, true)\n#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Pool.php(67): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Cache\\Frontend\\Factory->create(Array)\n#6 /var/w in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php on line 209

// * (ip and port modified)
```

I tryed to give the propper permissions to the folders with the commands:

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/
// or
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/
```

But none of them worked, I even tried with `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/` with same result.

I found this post: [Install issue permission and htaccess](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92681/install-issue-permission-and-htaccess)
and tried the solution proposed there:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
ServerName www.example.com:80
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And same permissions error is there.

I can't get to work this magento 2, I always get the permissions error, even granting all the folders with 777 permission.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I tried umask with no result. I created the file magento_umask in `<your Magento install dir>/magento_umask` and placed inside `007`, I also tried with `022. But still no luck.

I tryed giving permissions to apache group, and even adding the user with permissions to the apache group, but nothing worked.

Finally I've found somebody talking about SELinux modifying the permissions automatically, so I disabled the SELinux, and the everything worked.

Comment: Could you change the ownershop to the html folder with you logged in your account   sudo chown -R apache:<login user>  /var/www/html/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found that SELinux was modifying and blocking the permissions to the files and folders. So I've disabled it and the everything worked as expected.

https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/sec-sel-enable-disable.html

It works setting SELinux in `permissive` mode and `disabled` mode.

Don't forget to reboot the machine after changing this file.

I feel disabling it it's kinda insecure, but it's the only way I made it work.

Comment: page returns 404.... here is the link to a tutorial which allows to do the same
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-disable-selinux-on-centos-7/

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue with var/page_cache not writable.  OP's answer pointed me in the right direction.

Rather than disabling SELinux completely, need to update SELinux security context for following directories:

```
chcon -R --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t <your Magento install dir>/app/etc
chcon -R --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t <your Magento install dir>/var
chcon -R --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t <your Magento install dir>/pub/media
chcon -R --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t <your Magento install dir>/pub/static
```

As described in Magento docs here
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/security.html

Comment: thanks!! helped me

Answer (score 1):

Try below code with absolute path, no need to disable SELinux, it is working for me

```
chcon -R --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/app/etc 

chcon -R --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/var 

chcon -R --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/pub/media 

chcon -R --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/pub/static
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try below code.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/var folder
```

OR

Check Root folder ownership permission.

Ref - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html

Comment: give 777 permission to the `/var/www/html/var` folder is not working neither. And I found a bit confusing that documentation.

Comment: Can you change the ownershop to the html folder with you logged in your account like sudo chown -R apache:<login user> /var/www/html/ and set permission?

Comment: `sudo chown -R apache:root /var/www/html/` returns same error

Comment: You may try this - sudo chown -R root:apache /var/www/html/ and also execute the command chmod -R 0777 /var/www/html/var/

Comment: I still got `page_cache is not writable`

Comment: clear cache folder before you try the comment sudo chown -R root:apache /var/www/html/ and chmod -R 0777 /var/www/html/var/